# Close a tkinter Toplevel window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, toplevel

How to close a tkinter Toplevel window after pressing a button? I have already associated a command on the button, so I can't destroy the window.

I have more than one Toplevel in my class

Comment: Call `destroy()` on the `Toplevel` window. Also show what have you done so far.

Comment: you have to assign Toplevel to global (or class) variable so you could access it in other place. And then you can do `window.destroy()`. If you have many windows then you have to assign every window to separated variable or keep all of them on list.

Comment: @furas This is what I did. but I thought there was a smarter way to do it

Comment: What do you mean "smarter"? Why is saving a reference and then calling `destroy` on that reference not smart enough? Can you show some code that illustrates the problem that you're having?

Answer (score 0):

If your top window button must do stuff, then quit, you can call `top.destroy` after doing the stuff:

Maybe something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def do_that_and_close(top):
    print('doing that')
    top.destroy()

def launch_top():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    lbl = tk.Label(top, text='this is top')
    lbl.pack()    
    btn = tk.Button(top, text='do this and quit', command=lambda: do_that_and_close(top))
    btn.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
lbl = tk.Label(root, text='this is root')
lbl.pack()
root_btn = tk.Button(root, text='launch top', command=launch_top)
root_btn.pack()
quit_btn = tk.Button(root, text='quit', command=root.destroy)
quit_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```